# Understanding axis in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, axis

I have seen a couple of codes using `numpy.apply_along_axis` and I always have to test the codes to see how this works 'cause I didn't understand the `axis` idea in Python yet.

For example, I tested [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) simple codes from the reference.

I can see that for the first case it was took the first column of each row of the matrix, and in the second case, the row itself was considered.

So I build an example to test how this works with an array of matrices (the problem that took me to this axis question), which can also be seen as a 3d matrix, where each row is a matrix, right?

```
a = [[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]],[[4,5,6],[9,8,7]]]

import numpy
data = numpy.array([b for b in a])

def my_func(x):
    return (x[0] + x[-1]) * 0.5

b = numpy.apply_along_axis(my_func, 0, data)
b = numpy.apply_along_axis(my_func, 1, data)
```

Which gave me:

```
array([[ 2.5,  3.5,  4.5],
       [ 5.5,  5.5,  5.5]])
```

And:

```
array([[ 1.5,  2.5,  3.5],
       [ 6.5,  6.5,  6.5]])
```

For the first result I got what I expected. But for the second one, I though I would receive:

```
array([[ 2.,  3.],
       [ 5.,  8.]])
```

Then I though that maybe should be an `axis=2` and I got the previous result testing it. So, I'm wondering how this works to work it properly.

Thank you.

Comment: What's your intended result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `data=numpy.array(a)` is already enough, no need to use `numpy.array([b for b in a])`.

`data` is now a 3D [`ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) with the shape `(2,2,3)`, and has 3 axes `0, 1, 2`. The first axis has a length of 2, the second axis's length is also 2 and the third axis's length is 3.

Therefore both `numpy.apply_along_axis(my_func, 0, data)` and `numpy.apply_along_axis(my_func, 1, data)` will result in a 2D array of shape `(2,3)`. In both cases the shape is `(2,3)`, those of the remaining axes, 2nd and 3rd or 1st and 3rd.

`numpy.apply_along_axis(my_func, 2, data)` returns the `(2,2)` shape array you showed, where `(2,2)` is the shape of the first 2 axes, as you `apply` along the 3rd axis (by giving index `2`).

The way to understand it is whichever axis you apply along will be 'collapsed' into the shape of your `my_func`, which in this case returns a single value. The order and shape of the remaining axis will remain unchanged.

The alternative way to think of it is: `apply_along_axis` means apply that function to the values on that axis, for each combination of the remaining axis/axes. Fetch the result, and organize them back into the shape of the remaining axis/axes. So, if `my_func` returns a `tuple` of 4 values:

```
def my_func(x):
    return (x[0] + x[-1]) * 2,1,1,1
```

we will expect `numpy.apply_along_axis(my_func, 0, data).shape` to be `(4,2,3)`.

- See also [`numpy.apply_over_axes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_over_axes.html#numpy.apply_over_axes) for applying a function repeatedly over multiple axes

Answer (score 2):

Let there be an `array` of `shape (2,2,3)`. It can be seen that `axis 0`, `axis 1`, `axis 2` has 2 ,2, 3 data values respectively. 
These are the indexes of the elements of the array

```
[
    [
        [(0,0,0) (0,0,1), (0,0,2)],
        [(0,1,0) (0,1,1), (0,1,2)]
    ],
    [
        [(1,0,0) (1,0,1), (1,0,2)],
        [(1,1,0) (1,1,1), (1,1,2)]
    ]
]
```

Now **if you apply some operation along some axis, then vary the indexes along this axis only keeping the indices along the two other axis constant**.

Example: If we apply some operation F along `axis 0`, then the elements of the result would be

```
[
    [F((0,0,0),(1,0,0)), F((0,0,1),(1,0,1)), F((0,0,2),(1,0,2))],
    [F((0,1,0),(1,1,0)), F((0,1,1),(1,1,1)), F((0,1,2),(1,1,2))]
]
```

Along `axis 1`:

```
[
    [F((0,0,0),(0,1,0)), F((0,0,1),(0,1,1)), F((0,0,2),(0,1,2))],
    [F((0,1,0),(1,1,0)), F((0,1,1),(1,1,1)), F((0,1,2),(1,1,2))]
]
```

Along `axis 2`:

```
[
    [F((0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,0,2)), F((0,1,0),(0,1,1),(0,1,2))],
    [F((1,0,0),(1,0,1),(1,0,2)), F((1,1,0),(1,1,1),(1,1,2))]
]
```

Also the shape of the resulting array can be inferred by omitting the given axis in the shape of given data.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps checking the shape of your array will help clarify which axis is which;

```
print data.shape

>> (2,2,3)
```

This means that calling

```
numpy.apply_along_axis(my_func, 2, data)
```

should indeed give a 2x2 matrix, namely

```
array([[ 2.,  3.],
      [ 5.,  8.]])
```

because the **3rd axis (index 2)** has length 3, while the remaining axes are both length 2.

Comment: This is what I receive too. Didn't understand what is your question. :S

Comment: @pceccon: Apologies I'd misunderstood; perhaps it would help you to check the shape of the data - edited my answer.